# Why accessing out-of-bounds indices of dynamic array doesn't raise AV?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

In the VCL, `TByteDynArray` is defined as a dynamic array:

```
type TByteDynArray = array of Byte;
```

But it seems that no index bounds checking is done:

```
var
  DataBytes: System.Types.TByteDynArray;
  i: Integer;
begin
  SetLength(DataBytes, 2);
  DataBytes[5] := 222; // Accessing index beyond set length.
  i := DataBytes[5]; // `i` is now set to "222".
```

The code above runs without errors.

Why isn't an `AccessViolation` raised, like with a static array? What is the point of `SetLength` if you can access and modify 65536 bytes of memory of the array variable regardless of the length set?

Comment: range checking is disabled by default; use `$r+` to enable it

Comment: *The code above runs without errors.* Maybe. Maybe not. Whether or not there is an error is not predictable.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan From the testing I've done it reproducibly doesn't raise an error. What error could be raised?

Comment: You can never predict what is overwritten. Sometimes it is disaster, other times it will give subtle errors.

Comment: @LURD Oh I understand now. I presumed that every dynamic array reserves 65k of memory, which is how I'm able to write to any index of it, but I realise now that's silly. Thanks :)

Comment: You were just unlucky in that no error was raised. Another time you'd have written on something that matters and was being used elsewhere.

Comment: You are using a lot of incorrect assumptions as base and your question doesn't make much sense in result. Static array **MAY** not cause A/V presumed out of bound memory is allocated to something else. Dynamic array **MAY** cause A/V if allocated tightly below last page  boundary. However, I'm sure what accessing 3 bytes above 2 byte array boundary will never crash with default FastMM alignment. So your answer is - you are storing value 222 in padding bytes.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To detect array index out of bounds errors, set range check error on.

[Range Checking](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/en/Range_checking)

> The $R directive enables or disables the generation of range-checking code. In the {$R+} state, all array and string-indexing expressions are verified as being within the defined bounds, and all assignments to scalar and subrange variables are checked to be within range. If a range check fails, an ERangeError exception is raised (or the program is terminated if exception handling is not enabled).

This is default set to {$R-}, but I suggest to set it on, at least through the development phase.
It adds an extra overhead to the code, so this may be the reason it is off by default.

---

If you have a unit that is well tested and want to avoid range checking, add {$R-} at the top of the unit. This will override the project setting locally.

If you want to avoid range checking in a code block, this technique could be used:

```
{$IFOPT R+}
  {$DEFINE RestoreRangeCheck}
  {$R-}
{$ENDIF}

{- Some code here }

{$IFDEF RestoreRangeCheck}
  {$R+}
  {$UNDEF RestoreRangeCheck}
{$ENDIF}
```

Comment: Thank you for the useful answer. Could you give some guidance as to whether I should turn this on (instead of doing explicit range checks in code)? Why isn't this on by default?

Comment: @NewWorld You should *always* run with range checking and overflow checking turned on (at least in your Debug configuration). Make that the default for the IDE. Why this isn't on by default, beats me. A stupid design decision IMO

Comment: It's not on because people routinely define an array as `a = array[0..0] of integer` and than dynamically assign (a large block of) memory for it. See much of the VCL. In such a scenario you don't want `{$R+}`. However it should really be on by default.

Comment: @Johan That doesn't explain anything. The VCL code could readily use $R- or even better avoid this needles construct. If Emba cared they would enabled range and overflow checking by default. The fact that some VCL code is poor hardly justifies leaving newbs without a safety net.

Comment: @Johan, normally when you deliberately give up control, you make sure the code block is surrounded with range check off.